# Designing a many-to-one mobile app -> database -> desktop app project

Tags: c#, android, wpf, mobile

I wish to develop a project, where many mobile apps will interact with a desktop application using an intermediary database.

[image]

Mobile app: Android
Desktop app: C# WPF

The general idea is that the mobile app will take a record from the database, update it, publish it back to the database and then the desktop application will be able to read the updated data. I want to thoroughly design it before coding because I know it could be a potential nightmare down the line.

How would this work if more than one mobile app is currently writing to the database? Is there a "write queue" given that the first writer will lock the DB for writing?

Should the Mobile app be allowed to write to the database directly?  Or should there be a way of sending an "object" with all relevant data to the Desktop app, where the Desktop app can then be responsible for periodically writing to the database?

I'm guessing the best way would be that the database will be stored as a local copy on the Desktop, and pushed periodically to the cloud, but then as above, how do I send the data from the mobile app directly to the desktop without writing to an intermediary database?

Comment: I'm also investigating for web development. Did you think about using a webservice to interface your database. This way you can easily manage your queue list before writing into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a database synchronization tool like SymmetricDS or Daffodil:

It would run on each Android device, and on your central database computer, and perhaps on the desktop computer as well.

It would synchronize database changes over HTTP(S). You can setup policies as well for, say not giving everyone all of the data.

Your central database should support various levels of [serializability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability), and you can try implementing [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) to prevent simultaneous updates of the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try SAP's (formerly Sybase's) SQL Anywhere, which provides desktop, server and mobile versions of highly secured databases that get data-synced using the inbuilt Mobile Link technology. Very easy to install and work with. Even comes with a DBMS Management Tool, Sybase Central.  Easy to design schemas and setup how data should get synced between server/desktop/mobile DBs.  Also can be installed in various modern OSes.